# How to use Logic Analyzer and Event Viewer in Keil uVision with TM4C123GXL launchpad

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, keil, logic-analyzer, tm4c123g

I am using Keil uVision5 for programming TI launchpad TM4C123GXL with TIVA WARE Library.

How can I use the Logic Analyzer and Event Viewer in Keil uVision?

While in a debug mode, I tried to set up Logic Analyzer by adding a variable which alternate 0 and 1. But the output in the analyzer shows nothing. How can I correctly setup it?

[image]

Also how can I setup the Event Viewer? I could not find any help online that can help me with TM4C123. The help window give the option to configure Cortex-M device but it does not give options for TM4C123.

Comment: If I paid Keil for their products and didn't know how to apply them, I'd probably just email or call them up and ask. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I am using the evaluation version of Keil. I have asked the same question on ARM Community. Didn't got any response.

Comment: /@MasoodSalik Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: The issue was not resolved. However, I used an alternative technique. I pulled up a pin high at the different events, and monitor them via an external oscilloscope.